# Delete an Item from a List/Search for an Item in a list

Tags: java, list

I'm working on a lab where we have a phonebook program. The program opens a box where you then open a .bat file containing the list of names and numbers.

I can't figure out how to get my deleteMI function and searchMI function to work.

Any help is immensely appreciated

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PhoneBook extends Frame implements ActionListener, ItemListener {

MenuItem newMI, openMI, saveMI, saveAsMI, exitMI;
MenuItem searchMI, deleteMI, updateMI, newEntryMI, sortMI;
String fileName;
List nameList, numberList;
TextField lastName, firstName, phoneNumber;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public PhoneBook() {
    super("White Pages");  // set frame title
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());  // set layout

    // create menu bar
    MenuBar menubar = new MenuBar();
    setMenuBar(menubar);

    // create file menu
    Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
    menubar.add(fileMenu);
    newMI = fileMenu.add(new MenuItem("New"));
    newMI.addActionListener(this);
    openMI = fileMenu.add(new MenuItem("Open"));
    openMI.addActionListener(this);
    fileMenu.addSeparator();
    saveMI = fileMenu.add(new MenuItem("Save"));
    saveAsMI = fileMenu.add(new MenuItem("Save As ..."));
    fileMenu.addSeparator();
    exitMI = fileMenu.add(new MenuItem("Exit"));
    exitMI.addActionListener(this);

    // create edit menu
    Menu editMenu = new Menu("Edit");
    menubar.add(editMenu);
    updateMI = editMenu.add(new MenuItem("Update"));
    updateMI.addActionListener(this);
    newEntryMI = editMenu.add(new MenuItem("New Entry"));
    newEntryMI.addActionListener(this);
    deleteMI = editMenu.add(new MenuItem("Delete"));
    editMenu.addSeparator();
    searchMI = editMenu.add(new MenuItem("Search"));
    searchMI.addActionListener(this);
    sortMI = editMenu.add(new MenuItem("Sort"));

    // create phone list and controls
    Panel listPanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    add(listPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Label label = new Label("Name List", Label.LEFT);
    listPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    nameList = new List();
    nameList.addItemListener(this);
    numberList = new List();
    listPanel.add(nameList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Panel panel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    Panel editPanel = new Panel(new GridLayout(6, 1));
    panel.add(editPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    label = new Label("Last Name", Label.LEFT);
    editPanel.add(label);
    lastName = new TextField();
    editPanel.add(lastName);
    label = new Label("First Name", Label.LEFT);
    editPanel.add(label);
    firstName = new TextField();
    editPanel.add(firstName);
    label = new Label("Phone Number", Label.LEFT);
    editPanel.add(label);
    phoneNumber = new TextField();
    editPanel.add(phoneNumber);
}

// implementing ActionListener
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if(source == newMI) {
        nameList.removeAll();
        numberList.removeAll();
        fileName = null;
        display(-1);
        setTitle("White Pages");   // reset frame title
    }
    else if(source == openMI) {
        doOpen();
    }
    else if(source == exitMI) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(source == updateMI) {
        int index = nameList.getSelectedIndex();
        String name = lastName.getText().trim() + " " + firstName.getText().trim();
        String number = phoneNumber.getText().trim();
        if(index < 0) {  // add a new entry
            nameList.add(name);
            numberList.add(number);
            nameList.select(nameList.getItemCount()-1);
        }
        else {  // update an existing entry
            nameList.replaceItem(name, index);
            numberList.replaceItem(number, index);
            nameList.select(index);
        }
    }
    else if(source == newEntryMI) {
        nameList.select(-1);
        display(-1);            
    }

// Can't get delete to work     
    else if(source == deleteMI) {
        int name = nameList.getSelectedIndex();
        int number = numberList.getSelectedIndex();
       if(name >= 0){
        nameList.remove(name);
        numberList.remove(number);
       }                                                
    }


// Can't get search to work 
    else if(source == searchMI) {
        String searchName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,
                            "Please enter a name (last first) to search:");
        System.out.println("Name to search: " + searchName);
        int index = nameList.getSelectedIndex();
        String name = nameList.getItem(index);
            for(int i=0; i < nameList.getItemCount(); i++){
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(searchName)){

                    nameList.select(index);
                    System.out.println("We Found Him");
                }        
            }          
    }

else if(source == sortMI) {
        System.exit(0);




    }  


}








/**
 * Implementing ItemListener to display the selected entry
 */
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
    display(nameList.getSelectedIndex());
}

/**
 * method to specify and open a file
 */
private void doOpen() {
    // display file selection dialog
    FileDialog fDialog = new FileDialog(this, "Open ...", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fDialog.setVisible(true);
    // Get the file name chosen by the user
    String file = fDialog.getFile();
    // If user canceled file selection, return without doing anything.
    if(file == null)
        return;
    fileName = fDialog.getDirectory() + file;

    // Try to create a file reader from the chosen file.
    FileReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new FileReader(fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File Not Found: " + fileName,
                                      "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        doOpen();
        return;
    }
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    // remove items from before if any
    nameList.removeAll();
    numberList.removeAll();
    // Try to read from the input file one line at a time.
    try {
        int index;
        String name, number;
        String textLine = bReader.readLine();
        while (textLine != null) {
            index = textLine.indexOf((int) ',');
            if(index > 0) {
                name = textLine.substring(0, index);
                number = textLine.substring(index+1);
                nameList.add(name.trim());
                numberList.add(number.trim());
            }
            textLine = bReader.readLine();
        }
        bReader.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error reading file: " + ioe.toString(),
                                      "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }
    setTitle("White Pages: " +file);   // reset frame title
    nameList.select(0);
    display(0);
}

/**
 * method to display the current entry
 */
private void display(int index) {
    if(index < 0) {
        lastName.setText("");
        firstName.setText("");
        phoneNumber.setText("");
    }
    else {
        String name = nameList.getItem(index);
        int space = name.indexOf((int) ' ');
        lastName.setText(name.substring(0, space));
        firstName.setText(name.substring(space+1));
        phoneNumber.setText(numberList.getItem(index));
    }
}

/**
 * the main method
 */
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    // create frame
    System.out.println("Creating window ... ");
    PhoneBook frame = new PhoneBook();
  Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setSize(size.width/2, size.height/2);
    frame.setLocation(100, 100);

    System.out.println("Your Screen Size: " + size.width + " (width) x "
                       + size.height + " (height)");

    //Working on search functions

    String name1 = "John";
    String name2 = "James";
    if(name1.equalsIgnoreCase(name2)){
        System.out.println("The two names are the same");
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("The two names are different");

    //Working on Sort function

    String nameA = "John";
    String nameB = "James";
    if(nameA.compareToIgnoreCase(nameB) == 0) {
        System.out.println("The two names are the same");
    }
    else if (nameA.compareToIgnoreCase(nameB) < 0) 
        System.out.println("Name A comes before Name B");
    else 
        System.out.println("Name A comes after Name B");


    // add window closing listener
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    // show the frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

![enter image description here][1]}
```

Comment: I figured out part of the problem with delete... no ActionListener at the top.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Have you tried a debugger? What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Currently with the action listener on delete, its working but shifting the number to the next person instead of deleting it. With the searchMI function it's just doing nothing. Returns my system print line of the search name and then nothing else. I need it to select that person in the list so they will show up in the text fields on the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. you didn't add a actionListener to deleteMI
2. the searching loop is incorrect, it should be:

   ```
   else if(source == searchMI) {
       String searchName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,
               "Please enter a name (last first) to search:");
       System.out.println("Name to search: " + searchName);
       String name;
       for(int i=0; i < nameList.getItemCount(); i++){
           name = nameList.getItem(i);
           if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(searchName)){
               nameList.select(i);
                   //add this code for display data:
               String[] n = name.split(" ");
               firstName.setText(n[0]);
               lastName.setText(n[1]);
               phoneNumber.setText(numberList.getItem(i));
                   //end
               System.out.println("We Found Him");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

But search works only for "Last Name + First Name" String.

You used index variable in incorrect way. It did't change with loop.

The problem with delete is coused by `int number = numberList.getSelectedIndex();` - you don't have selected item (at least in code above, there is no visible numberList at all), so it return -1. It couse ArrayOutOfBoundsException. So implement this solution:

```
    else if(source == deleteMI) {
        int index = nameList.getSelectedIndex();
        if(index >= 0){
            nameList.remove(index);
            numberList.remove(index);
        }
    }
```

As for a sort method, it is all i can do now:

```
    else if(source == sortMI){
        String[] list = nameList.getItems();
        String[] nums = numberList.getItems();
        Arrays.sort(list);
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        for(int i = 0; i<list.length;i++){
            nameList.replaceItem(list[i],i);
            numberList.replaceItem(nums[i],i);
        }
        nameList.revalidate();
        numberList.revalidate();
    }
```

it is not to elegant code, but as far as I know, it works. I hope it will suits your needs.

Comment: I've changed the code to reflect your solution but it's still not doing anything besides giving me the system print out of the name to be searched for. I need it to select that name in the list.

Comment: @Devin are you using first and last name? in my code this solution works

Comment: You're right, I see it's working now. How do I get the found name to show up in the text fields on the left. It selected the persons name in the list, but did not update the left side boxes.

Comment: @Devin i added a code for displaying first and last name, and phone number, I hope it what you wanted

Comment: That worked perfectly! The search function works great now and deleteMI is working almost perfectly. Thank you @m.cekiera. I also need to sort the list by last name under the sort function, do you know how I could do that?

Comment: I added in the sortMI function spot, I'm still not sure how to sort it by Last Name, while keeping all the data in the correct places. IE corresponding phone numbers with the correct people.

Comment: Also if anyone has any idea why delete isn't functioning perfectly that would help immensly. It currently removes the name but not the number and shifts the old number to the next person. It also throws tons of errors none of which I know the meaning of.

Comment: @Devin I add some changes to my post you may find useful